# Why is this approximation of polynomial root so accurate?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I have an engineering problem where I have to find the smallest positive real root of a polynomial in $x$:
$$Ax^5+Bx^3 - C = 0$$
Instead of solving numerically, I want simple approximative formulas ("design equations") that describe the behaviour. For that matter, I split the problem into two regimes:

- Large $x$: $\ \ \ \ x^5$ is dominant $\Longrightarrow \ \ Ax^5 \approx C  \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ x \approx \sqrt[5]{C/A} =: x_A$
- Small $x$: $\ \ \ \ x^3$ is dominant $\Longrightarrow \ \ Bx^3 \approx C  \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ x \approx \sqrt[3]{C/B} =: x_B$

The approximations work well below/above a certain threshold on $x$, but require an ugly case distinction. In order to avoid that and having something smoother than 
$$x \approx \min\{x_A, x_B\}$$
I tried Pythagorean-style combination of the inverses (inspired by the resistance of parallel circuits in electrical engineering) and found that
$$x \approx 1\Big/ \ \left\|\left(\begin{matrix}
  1/x_A \\
  1/x_B
 \end{matrix}\right)\right\|_4 = 1 \Big/ \sqrt[4]{1/x_A^4 + 1/x_B^4}$$
is a really, really good approximation. Pretty much perfect.
That leads me to **my actual question:** Is it possible to argue why that 4-norm is such an amazing approximation? Does my initial polynomial have a certain structure that explains the high accuracy of my approximation?

Since I want to present/defend that stuff, I'd appreciate some sophistication.

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ positive? If so the "smallest positive real root" is the only real root.

Comment: For example, the sole real root of $17x^5 + 41x^3 - 105$ is approximately $1.17624...$; the approximation gives $1.17849...$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes they are positive. And sure, since $f(x) = Ax^5 + Bx^3$ is strictly increasing, there is only one relevant solution.

Comment: What do you mean by a "really, really good approximation", and have you tried lots of values of $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn No I haven't done exhaustive tests with all kinds of $A,B$ combos, only what my problem yielded. Here is what I mean with great approximation: http://i.imgur.com/7Bfl8nt.png Only ridiculous zooming exposes some error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten

$$\left(\frac x{x_A}\right)^5+\left(\frac x{x_B}\right)^3-1=0.$$

With $y=\dfrac x{x_A}$ and $r=\dfrac{x_A}{x_B}$, a single parameter remains:

$$y^5+r^3y^3-1=0.$$

Then
$$r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-y^5}{y^3}}=\frac1y\sqrt[3]{1-y^5},$$ can be compared to your approximation
$$y=\frac1{\sqrt[4]{1+r^4}},$$i.e.
$$r=\sqrt[4]{\frac1{y^4}-1}=\frac1y\sqrt[4]{1-y^4}.$$
The agreement is indeed excellent on a wide range [abscissa $y$, ordinate $r$]:
[image]

For small $y$, both behaviors are identical, $\dfrac1y$. For $y$ close to $1$, behaviors are similar, approximately $\sqrt[3]{5(1-y)}$ and$\sqrt[4]{4(1-y)}$, and a blend in between.

The good agreement is explained by the fact that the functional relations are similar, with the exponent $4$ intermediate between $3$ and $5$ (but the value $4$ has nothing "magical").

Comment: Using Yves's parametrization, the absolute value of the difference between the true $y$ and your approximation turns out to be at most $0.01171$.  The maximum absolute difference occurs at approximately $r = 0.66145$, where the true $y \approx  0.94545$ while the approximation is $0.95716$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: you can try slightly lower values than $4$ for the exponent, such as $3.7$.

Comment: Yes, I can.  The best in terms of maximum absolute difference seems to be approximately $3.85$ (i.e. approximation $(1 + r^{3.85})^{-1/3.85}$), where the maximum absolute difference is about $0.007608$.

Comment: Does this mean that there's an exact solution, rather than the approximation that the OP is using

Comment: Amazing answer, very intuitive and accounts for everything I wished for, thank you. I reproduced all your steps.

Comment: @DrXorile I don't think so, because you cannot rearrange the $r,y$ formula towards $y = f(r)$ and in consequence $x  = g(x_A,x_B)$ for the 3,5 case while that's already done for the 4,4 case. The thing is, my approximation turns Yves' initial polynomial into $(x/x_A)^4 + (x/x_B)^4 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: @DrXorile: the exact solution is for the $y\to r$ relation, which cannot be inverted by a closed formula, unfortunately.